# Mod Rewrite Subdomain to PHP with GET variable

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to wrap my head around mod rewrite, but can't seem to figure this out.

Is there a way I could do the following?

User types in: `http://wildcard.mydomain.com`

Silently writes to:

```
http://mydomain.com/index.php?username=wildcard
```

Comment: Yes there is. What actually you cannot get?

Comment: Before using .htaccess, i think, you should create a general virtual subdomain with using asterisk * in your host.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and set a wildcard for a subdomain, and set it to redirect to something that exists. For some reason, just fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must capture the first part of the domain in a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) and then use this in a [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule). The additional `RewriteCond`s are there to prevent `www.mydomain.com` and `index.php` being rewritten

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule .* /index.php?username=%1 [L]
```

But this is only a small part of the needed functionality. Additionally, you must setup DNS entries for all of your `username.mydomain.com` domain names or setup a [wildcard DNS entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) `*.mydomain.com` pointing to your host.

Otherwise, the client tries to contact `jcraine.mydomain.com`, for example, and doesn't find a DNS entry and complains.

If this is a [virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#virtualhost), you must also add a [`ServerAlias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#serveralias) for each of your usernames

```
ServerAlias jcraine.mydomain.com
```

or a wildcard catching all subdomains

```
ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
```

Comment: Thanks for this Olaf. I really appreciate your thoroughness. I spoke to my host and found there was a problem with wildcard domains not going through. All resolved now so was able to get your code to work nicely. For the moment, I'll use the wildcard method. But will most likely need to setup the other stuff so users can point their own domains at their personalised app space. Your info will help me figure out how to go about it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Should do the trick.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(users)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$    http://www.example.com/?username=%1 [L]
```